# How can i subtract arbitrary 2 lists in racket?

Tags: racket

I want to define a function that consumes 2 lists and do subtraction resulting another list.

For example, when list1 is '(a a b b c) and list2 is '(a b), the subtraction result should be '(a b c).

I tried to implement it by lambda and remove, ended up making sevral lists.

I really have no idea how to do this.

Comment: How would the result be from `(substract '(a) '(a a))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
#lang racket
(define (subtract xs ys)
  (if (empty? ys)
      xs
      (subtract (remove (first ys) xs) (rest ys))))

(subtract '(a a b b c) '(a b))
```

Comment: Oh, it is quite simple once i knew how to do it. Really helpful. Thank you very much!